# Add a tabularx near a picture which is also inserted in a tabularx

Tags: tabularx

In my document, to place text next to my images, I opted for a environment `tabularx` .

In a few cases, I need to add an array (so another environment ) but I get error messages and it doesn't work.

Currently, to counter the problem, I have placed the second environment `tabularx`  after the first but it is less pretty!

Is there a solution for this?
thank you in advance

My example :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, top=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{enumitem}  %pour l'option [resume] qui permet de reprendre la numérotation
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{appendix}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{picinpar}

\usepackage[european, RPvoltages, straightvoltages]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{colorlinks=false, linkcolor=black}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\Roman{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\alph{subsubsection}}
\newcommand{\expo}{\textrm{e}} %pour écrire e puissance
\newcommand{\ofg}[1]{\og{}#1\fg{}}
\newcommand{\txtmesure}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\newcommand{\txtpgm}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\newcommand{\txtprelim}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\newcommand{\txtmanip}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\newcommand{\txtinterpretation}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\newcommand{\itempgm}{\begin{itemize}[label=\ding{47}]}
\newcommand{\itempgmbis}{\begin{itemize}[label=\ding{49}]}
\newcommand{\itemmanip}{\begin{itemize}[label=\ding{45}]}
\newcommand{\itemcomplement}{\begin{itemize}[label=\ding{80}]}
\newcommand{\itemcomplementbis}{\begin{itemize}[label=\ding{79}]}


\begin{document}
\subsection{Capteur de force}
\subsubsection{Capteur utilisé}

\textbf{Principe du capteur :} un capteur de force (FSR, Force Sensing Resistor) est un capteur dont la résistance varie avec la pression qui lui est appliquée : à force nulle, sa résistance est élevée et diminue lorsqu’on lui exerce une force.


\begin{center}
    \renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} cX @{}}
\includegraphics[width=50mm, valign=c]{capteur_force}
    & \textbf{Manipulation : }programme capteur\_force\_etalonnage.ino
\itemmanip{}
    \item Le capteur de force est inséré dans un bloc de mousse. Faire les branchements électriques (\emph{comme il est déconseillé de chauffer le capteur pour éviter d’abîmer la partie active du capteur, il vaut mieux éviter de le souder à un fil électrique});
    \item Placer une bouteille d’eau vide sur la mousse (surmontée éventuellement d'un entonnoir en plastique) ;
    \item Pour différents volumes d’eau (et donc différentes forces appliquées au capteur), noter la résistance du capteur :
\end{itemize}
\end{tabularx}
\end{center}

    \begin{tabularx}{0.5\linewidth}{|c||*{7}{>{\centering \arraybackslash}X|}}\hline
    volume d'eau (\si{\liter}) & 0.5 & 0.7 & 0.9 & 1.1 & 1.3 & 1.5 \\ 
    \hline
    force (\si{\newton}) & 5 & 7 & 9 & 11 & 13 & 15  \\ 
    \hline 
    Résistance (\si{\kohm}) &  &  &  & & &  \\
    \hline
    \end{tabularx}
    
\itemmanip{}    
    \item Transférer les documents dans un logiciel de traitement (voir \ref{sec:traitement_donnees} \nameref{sec:traitement_donnees}) ;
    \item Modéliser les points obtenus par une fonction inverse de type $R=a/F + b$.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think using `tabularx` for this purpose makes a lot of sense actually. I recommend using `minipages`, which allows you to put any LaTeX objects next to each other (more or less).

Here is an example using some of your code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, top=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{enumitem}  %pour l'option [resume] qui permet de reprendre la numérotation
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newenvironment{manip}{\begin{itemize}[label=\ding{45}]}{\end{itemize}}
\usepackage{booktabs}


\begin{document}
    \subsection{Capteur de force}
    \subsubsection{Capteur utilisé}
    
    \textbf{Principe du capteur :} un capteur de force (FSR, Force Sensing Resistor) est un capteur dont la résistance varie avec la pression qui lui est appliquée : à force nulle, sa résistance est élevée et diminue lorsqu’on lui exerce une force.
                
\begin{minipage}{.22\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, valign=c]{example}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.78\linewidth}
    \textbf{Manipulation : }programme capteur\_force\_etalonnage.ino
    \begin{manip}
        \item Le capteur de force est inséré dans un bloc de mousse. Faire les branchements électriques (\emph{comme il est déconseillé de chauffer le capteur pour éviter d’abîmer la partie active du capteur, il vaut mieux éviter de le souder à un fil électrique});
        \item Placer une bouteille d’eau vide sur la mousse (surmontée éventuellement d'un entonnoir en plastique) ;
        \item Pour différents volumes d’eau (et donc différentes forces appliquées au capteur), noter la résistance du capteur :
    \end{manip}
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}[t][2.2cm][b]{.5\linewidth}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{Xcccccc}
    \toprule
    volume d'eau (\si{\liter}) & 0.5 & 0.7 & 0.9 & 1.1 & 1.3 & 1.5 \\ \midrule
    force (\si{\newton}) & 5 & 7 & 9 & 11 & 13 & 15  \\ \midrule
    Résistance (\si{\kohm}) &  &  &  & & &  \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t][3.0cm][b]{.5\linewidth}
    \begin{manip}
    \item Transférer les documents dans un logiciel de traitement (voir \ref{sec:traitement_donnees} \nameref{sec:traitement_donnees}) ;
    \item Modéliser les points obtenus par une fonction inverse de type $R=a/F + b$.
    \end{manip}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT:** While I am at it, I also defined a new environment `manip` based on your `newcommand` for the lists, which makes it a bit easier for your editor to see when an environment begins and ends.

**EDIT2:** I added the optional arguments I referred to in the comments below. The height differences here are due to the different spacings above the `itemize` and `tabularx` environments. The `minipages` are now matched at the top (first optional argument, takes b, t, and c), have a defined height (second optional argument, takes any length) and the text is flushed to the bottom (third argument, takes t and c). Note also, that for the `minipages` to appear next to each other, there may not be an empty line between the two.

Comment: thanks for the solution. Is it possible to add a margin at the top of the ```minipage``` to leave more room with the preceding text (and avoid using a ```\bigbreak```)?

Comment: The height of the minipage will be that of the content. So, a ‘\vspace*{}’ at the top should do the trick. But then you might need to add the optional alignment parameter to the minipage. By default, it will be centered.

Comment: Turns out, there is an easier option. minipage has three optional arguments, the relative positioning to each other, the definite height and the vertical alignment within the page. I’ll modify my answer tomorrow.

Comment: thanks for your response